# A special harmonic series discovered by Jonathan Borwein and David Bailey

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request

In the previous question here [An advanced harmonic series of weight $5$ with harmonic numbers $\overline{H}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458334/an-advanced-harmonic-series-of-weight-5-with-harmonic-numbers-overlineh-n/3458445#3458445) I mentioned a famous harmonic series discovered by **Jonathan Borwein** and **David Bailey** and that is also found in their books, like for example **Mathematics by experiment**, page $60$.

The series I'm talking about, with an adjusted denominator, is

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}$$
>   $$=\frac{19}{8}\log (2) \zeta (4) +\frac{7}{4}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3} \log ^3(2)\zeta (2) +\frac{3 }{4}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{167 }{32}\zeta (5)$$
>   $$-\frac{1}{30} \log ^5(2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
>   where $\displaystyle \overline{H}_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}.$

**Question:** What sources do you know (papers, books) where this series is calculated by real methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution by Cornel Ioan Valean** (in large steps)

Let's recall first Botez-Catalan identity, $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots-\frac{1}{2n}=H_{2n}-H_n$,  and then use it to calculate the difference $H_m-\overline{H}_m$, where we consider the cases $m=2n$ and $m=2n+1$. So. for $m=2n$, we have $H_{2n}-\overline{H}_{2n}=H_n$ and for $m=2n+1$, we get $H_{2n+1}-\overline{H}_{2n+1}=H_n.$

Also, we have that $\displaystyle \frac{(H_n-\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}=\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-2\frac{H_n\overline{H}_n}{n^3}+\frac{(\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}$. Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(H_n-\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n\overline{H}_n}{n^3}$$
$$\text{\{we split the first series in the right-hand side according to $n$ even and odd\}}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^3}-\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n\overline{H}_n}{n^3}$$
$$=\frac{19}{8}\log (2) \zeta (4) +\frac{7}{4}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3} \log ^3(2)\zeta (2) +\frac{3 }{4}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{167 }{32}\zeta (5)$$
$$-\frac{1}{30} \log ^5(2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
and at this point all the series are known. The first series from penultimate line can be calculated using Cornel's *Master Theorem of Series* (Ali Shather nicely explains Cornel's method in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3377671), the second series is immediately obtained by using the Abels's summation (a similar approach to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259984, and the precise value is also given by Ali Shather in this post [Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^2}{(2n+1)^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3375890)), the third series appears in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, and finally, the last series is calculated in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458445 where you may find Cornel's solution.

End of story.

All details will appear in a new paper.

**Update**: the evaluation of the series appears in the preprint, [Two advanced harmonic series of weight 5 involving skew-harmonic numbers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337937502_Two_advanced_harmonic_series_of_weight_5_involving_skew-harmonic_numbers).

Answer (score 3):

**A second solution by Cornel Ioan Valean** (in large steps)

We want to split the series based on parity and the use of Botez-Catalan identity, and then we write

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\overline{H}_n)^2}{n^3}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\overline{H}_{2n})^2}{(2n)^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\overline{H}_{2n+1})^2}{(2n+1)^3}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{8}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(H_{2 n+1}\right){}^2}{(2 n+1)^3}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}^2}{ (2n)^3}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2}{(2 n+1)^3}-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{(2 n+1)^4}$$
$$-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2n)^3}-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^3}$$
$$=\frac{19}{8}\log (2) \zeta (4) +\frac{7}{4}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3} \log ^3(2)\zeta (2) +\frac{3 }{4}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{167 }{32}\zeta (5)$$
$$-\frac{1}{30} \log ^5(2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
where the first three series may be easily extracted from the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, for the fourth series see the previous solution, then with respect to the fifth series you may see the generalized series in the paper [A new powerful strategy of calculating a class of alternating Euler sums by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333999069_A_new_powerful_strategy_of_calculating_a_class_of_alternating_Euler_sums), and the last two series are calculated in the paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonic series with a weight 5 structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$ by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055_On_the_calculation_of_two_essential_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n).

End of story.