# Closed form for the skew-harmonic sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n \overline{H}_n}{n^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm, euler-sums

In a post found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458334/an-advanced-harmonic-series-of-weight-5-with-harmonic-numbers-overlineh-n/3458445#3458445) it is mentioned that a closed form for the so-called *younger brother* (younger in the sense the power in the denominator is only squared, rather than cubed as in the linked question) skew-harmonic sum
$$S = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n \overline{H}_n}{n^2}$$
can be found, though none is given. Here $H_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th *harmonic number* while $\overline{H}_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k}$ is the $n$th *skew-harmonic number*.

> I seek the closed-form expression for the sum $S$.

My thoughts on a possible alternative approach to that suggested in the link is as follows. Since
$$\ln 2 - \overline{H}_n = (-1)^n \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1 + x} \, dx,$$
then
$$H_n \overline{H}_n = \ln 2 H_n -(-1)^n H_n \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1 + x} \, dx.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
S &= \ln 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n x^n}{n^2} \, dx\\
&= 2 \ln 2 \zeta (3) - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n (-x)^n}{n^2} \, dx,
\end{align}
since $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} = 2 \zeta (3)$.

I then thought of perhaps using the following known generating function of
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} x^n = \operatorname{Li}_3 (x) - \operatorname{Li}_3 (1-x) + \ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - x) + \frac{1}{2} \ln x \ln^2 (1 - x) + \zeta (3),$$
but this leads to complex valued logs and polylogs which I would rather avoid.

---

**Continuing**

Continuing on using the generating function, we see that
\begin{align}
S &= 2 \ln 2 \zeta (3) - \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3 (-x)}{1 + x} \, dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx\\
& \qquad - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 + x) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (-x) \ln^2 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx - \zeta (3) \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x}.
\end{align}
Surprisingly, indefinite integrals for all integrals appearing above can be readily found. Here:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)}{1 + x} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}^2_2 (-x) + \operatorname{Li}_3 (-x) \ln (1 + x) \Big{|}_0^1 = \frac{5}{16} \zeta (4) - \frac{3}{4} \ln 2 \zeta (3)\\[2ex]
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx &= \operatorname{Li}_4 (1 + x) \Big{|}_0^1 = \operatorname{Li}_4 (2) - \zeta (4)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 + x) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx &= \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 + x) \ln (1 + x) - \operatorname{Li}_4 (1 + x) \Big{|}_0^1\\
&= \operatorname{Li}_3 (2) \ln 2 - \operatorname{Li}_4 (2) + \zeta (4)\\[2ex]
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (-x) \ln^2 (1 + x)}{1 + x} \, dx &= -2 \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 + x) - \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 + x) \ln^2 (1 + x)\\
& \qquad + 2 \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 + x) \ln (1 + x) \Big{|}_0^1\\
&= -2 \operatorname{Li}_4 (2) - \operatorname{Li}_2 (2) \ln^2 2 + 2 \operatorname{Li}_3 (2) \ln 2 + 2 \zeta (4)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x} &= \ln 2
\end{align}
Thus
$$S = \frac{7}{4} \ln 2 \zeta (3) - \frac{53}{16} \zeta (4) + 3 \operatorname{Li}_4 (2) - 2 \operatorname{Li}_3 (2) \ln 2 + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}_2 (2) \ln^2 2.$$
Now finding values for $\operatorname{Li}_n (2)$ when $n = 2, 3$, and $4$. In each case the *principal* value is found.

1. $n = 2$ case

Using 
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (z) + \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - z) = \zeta (2) - \ln z \ln (1 - z),$$
setting $z = 2$ gives
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (2) = \frac{3}{2} \zeta (2) - i\pi \ln 2.$$

2. $n = 3$ case

Using
$$\operatorname{Li}_3 (z) = \operatorname{Li}_3 \left (\frac{1}{z} \right ) - \frac{1}{6} \ln^3 (-z) - \zeta (2) \ln (-z),$$
setting $z = 2$ gives
$$\operatorname{Li}_3 (2) = \frac{21}{24} \zeta (3) + \frac{3}{2} \zeta (2) \ln 2 - \frac{i \pi}{2} \ln^2 2.$$

3. $n = 4$ case

Finally, from the result given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467889/quadirlogarithm-value-operatornameli-4-left-frac12-right/467989#467989) one has
$$\operatorname{Li}_4(2) = 2 \zeta (4) - \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) - \frac{i \pi}{6} \ln^3 2 + \zeta (2) \ln^2 2 - \frac{1}{24} \ln^4 2.$$

Plugging in all the pieces, we finally arrive at
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n \overline{H}_n}{n^2} = \frac{43}{16} \zeta (4) - 3 \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) - \frac{1}{8} \ln^4 2 + \frac{3}{4} \zeta (2) \ln^2 2.$$
*Magical!!*

Comment: Why not this: $1+1/2+1/3+ . . ,+1/n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}$, $1-1/2+1/3-1/4 . . ,+1/n=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$, so $H_nH_n^-/n^2=\frac{1}{n^2-1}$

Comment: Just follow Cornels second solution in that link you provided.

Comment: It would be interesting to try to develop your way further. More ways in place are always welcome and good to know & have.

Comment: @user97357329 I continued my generating function approach and, somewhat unbelievably, managed to arrive at the desired closed form. Truly amazing!

Comment: @omegadot This is fantastic. Congrats! (maybe a similar approach would also work for the case with weight $5$?)

Comment: @AliShather see the magical way above. :-)

Comment: @user97357329 elegant ..

Comment: $\operatorname{Li}_3(2)$ can be simplified to $\frac{21}{24}\zeta(3)+\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)-\frac{i \pi}{2}\ln^22$ as $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: @Ali Shather Thanks for picking up this simplification I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **Cornel's** strategy here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459740, we have

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n \overline{H}_n}{n^2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n} \overline{H}_{2n}}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n+1} \overline{H}_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}$$
>   $$=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2 n}^2}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2 n+1}^2}{(2 n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(2 n+1)^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
>   $$=\frac{43}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac{3}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{8}\log^4(2)-3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$

where the hardest sums (the last two ones) use the strategy in this paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonic series with a weight 5 structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$ by C.I. Valean.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055)

**A first note:** The hardest sums in closed-form are
$$i) \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^2}=\frac{13}{32}\zeta(4)+\frac{7}{8}\log(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{24}\log^4(2)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
$$ii) \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{12}\log^4(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{7}{8}\log(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{4}\zeta(4)+2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$ and are immediately extracted by following the strategy in the paper mentioned above.
These results I took directly form Cornel's page [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2264971916932927&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater) and [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2266698973426888&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater), to avoid boring calculations.

**A second note:** From the strategy in this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268851) one may obtain immediately that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(2 n+1)^3}=\frac{45}{32}\zeta(4)-\frac{7}{4}\log(2)\zeta(3).$$

Further, the first two sums from the second line may be immediately reduced to sums that are pretty known and they may also be found in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

**A third note**: The weight $5$ version of the present series may be found and calculated in the paper [Two advanced harmonic series of weight 5 involving skew-harmonic numbers by C.I. Valean.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337937502) As seen in the paper, the present series can also be approached in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Following the same approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459740)

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n\overline{H}_n}{n^2}=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{H_n\overline{H}_n}{n^2}$$

Now use $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(2n)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(2n+1)$$

$$\Longrightarrow S=1+\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}\overline{H}_{2n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}\overline{H}_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}$$

$$=1+\frac14S_1+S_2$$

For $S_1$, use $\overline{H}_{2n}=H_{2n}-H_n$

$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}^2}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{n^2}$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^2}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}^2}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{n^2}$$

For $S_2$, use $\overline{H}_{2n+1}=H_{2n+1}-H_n$

\begin{align}
S_2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}^2}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}H_n}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}^2}{(2n+1)^2}-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}^2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}^2}{(n+1)^2}-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^2}{n^2}-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}^2}{n^2}-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
\end{align}

and all these sums are known and the hardest ones are

[$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nH_{2n}}{n^2}=4\operatorname{Li_4}\left( \frac12\right)+\frac{13}{8}\zeta(4)+\frac72\ln2\zeta(3)-\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac16\ln^42$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202316/how-to-find-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nh-2nn2-using-real-analysis-and-i)

and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n+1)^2}$ which I think was calculated by Cornel.

Answer (score 1):

**Different approach**

From [this paper](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0123134909Boyadz.pdf) in page $95$ Eq $(5)$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{H}_n\frac{x^n}{n}=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)-\ln2\ln(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)$$

multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ then $\int_0^1$ and use the fact that $-\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n}{n}$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{H}_nH_n}{n^2}=\underbrace{-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large \mathcal{I}}+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large \mathcal{J}}$$
$$+\ln2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{2\zeta(3)}+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{-\zeta(2)}\tag1$$

---

**Evaluation of $\mathcal{J}$**

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^3}$$
the last sum is calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3219475)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^3}=2\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{11}4\zeta(4)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^42$$

> $$\mathcal{J}=-2\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{11}4\zeta(4)-\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{12}\ln^42$$

---

**Evaluation of $\mathcal{I}$**

by Integration by parts twice we have

$$\mathcal{I}=\underbrace{-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1+x}\ dx}_{\large \mathcal{I}_1}+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large \mathcal{I}_2}-\ln2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{2\zeta(3)}$$

$\mathcal{I}_1$ was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513994), using Landens identity $-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)+\frac12\ln^2(1-x)$

$$\mathcal{I}_1=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}{1+x}\ dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx$$

where the first integral is calculated [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2374024339361017&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater)

$$\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{29}{16} \zeta (4)+\frac{1}{4}\ln ^22 \zeta (2) -\frac{1}{8} \ln ^42$$

and

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3y}{2-y}\ dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3y \ dy=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^nn^4}=-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)$$

$$\Longrightarrow \mathcal{I}_1=\boxed{-3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{29}{16} \zeta (4)+\frac{1}{4}\ln ^22 \zeta (2) -\frac{1}{8} \ln ^42}$$

---

For $\mathcal{I}_2$, use $a^2b=\frac16(a+b)^3-\frac16(a-b)^3-\frac13b^3$ where $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$

$$\Longrightarrow \mathcal{I}_2=\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{1-x^2=y}-\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y}-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{x}\ dx$$

$$=\frac1{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3y}{1-y}\ dy}_{-6\zeta(4)}-\frac13\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3y}{1-y^2}\ dy}_{-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(4)}-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{x}\ dx$$

For $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{x}\ dx$, we have a nice generalization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3440584)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n(1+x)}{x}\ dx=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)+\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n\choose k}\ln^{n-k}(2)\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)$$

$$\Longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{x}\ dx=6\zeta(4)-\frac{21}{4}\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac32\ln^22\zeta(2)-\frac14\ln^42-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)$$

$$\Longrightarrow \mathcal{I}_2=\boxed{2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(4)+\frac{7}{4}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac1{12}\ln^42}$$

Combine the boxed results we get

> $$ \mathcal{I}=-\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{19}{16}\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{4}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac14\ln^22\zeta(2)\frac1{24}\ln^42$$

Now substitute the results of $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ in $(1)$ we get

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n \overline{H}_n}{n^2} = - 3 \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right )+\frac{43}{16} \zeta (4)   + \frac{3}{4}  \ln^2 2\zeta (2)- \frac{1}{8} \ln^4 2$$